# PHP accepted nl2br and real_escape_string

Tags: php

I have a textarea input which is allow user to enter texts with line-break,

```
$desc = nl2br($mysqli->real_escape_string(ucfirst($_POST['desc'])));
```

but this cause a problem to saved into database, the `nl2br` supposed to output `<br />` but it was not, I wanted my textarea field could be accepted single quoted and be able to avoid sql injection all the time, and also display text as with line break. What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: The way to avoid SQL injection when you're using MySQLi is prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: Have you tried this , this also prevent sql injection `$mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['desc']));  `

Comment: also, instead of `nl2br`ing it when it goes **into** the db, you could `nl2br` the data when it comes **out of** the db. This will preserve original format (newline chars are more portable than html `<br>` tags. Also, what if you want to put it back into a textarea? you're just going to have to reverse it anyways) as well as save a few bytes of space in the db.